# $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $\int f_n \to \int f$. Prove that for each $A\in \mathcal{A}$ we have $\int_{A} f_n \to \int_{A} f$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is a measure space, each $f_n$ is integrable and non-negative, $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $\int f_n \to \int f$. Prove that for each $A\in \mathcal{A}$ we have $$\int_{A} f_n \to \int_{A} f$$

My try:

$f_n \chi_{A} \to f\chi_{A}$ a.e.

I've tried Lebesgue dominance but I can't go further than $|f_n\chi_{A}| \leq f_n $
I thought it would be great if $\sup f_n$ could be integrable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of [Scheffé's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma), and we can adapt its proof to OP's problem:

**Solution.** By Fatou's lemma,

$$ \int_A f \, \mathrm{d}\mu
= \int_A \liminf_{n\to\infty} f_n  \, \mathrm{d}\mu
\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_A f_n  \, \mathrm{d}\mu. \tag{1} $$

Replacing $A$ by $X\setminus A$ in $\text{(1)}$, we also have

\begin{align*}
\int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu - \int_A f \, \mathrm{d}\mu
&\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \left( \int_X f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu - \int_A f_n  \, \mathrm{d}\mu \right) \\
&= \left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu \right) - \left( \limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_A f_n  \, \mathrm{d}\mu \right).
\end{align*}

Now invoking the assumption that $\int_X f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu \to \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu$, this implies

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_A f_n  \, \mathrm{d}\mu \leq \int_A f \, \mathrm{d}\mu. \tag{2} $$

Combining $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ proves the desired equality.

Answer (score 1):

There is a generalized version of Dominated Convergence theorem:

If $f_n\rightarrow f$, $|f_n|\leq g_n$, $g_n\rightarrow g$, $\int g_n\rightarrow \int g$, and $f_n,g_n,f,g$ are all integrable, then $\int f_n\rightarrow \int f$.